# Try Except with general python exceptions

Tags: python, error-handling

I want to catch python errors (python defined errors like TypeError, DivisionByZeroError, and so forth. I want my code to look something like.

```
try
<python code>

except <GeneralError>:
<send general error to user>
```

At all documentation examples, I have to choose a specific type of error - how many I use a general error that I can send (so try except doesnt work either because I lose knowledge of what the error is)

Comment: Sorry your english doesn't make sense.   the most commonly used "general" exception would be `Exception`

Answer (score 2):

`Exception` is the base class of all the exception types you might reasonably want to catch.

```
try:
    ...
except Exception as exc:
    ...
```

Unless you plan on re-raising the exception, you almost certainly want to catch something more specific, so that you only catch the exceptions you *know* you can handle to allow your code to continue safely. (Note that `StopIteration` and `StopAsyncIteration` are both subclasses of `Exception`; if you catch one of them, you almost certainly do not want to ignore it.)